# Word Automation Service-Item Added Event not firing

Tags: service, ms-word, automation, eventreceiver

I am using Word Automation Services to convert Word Documents to PDF. I have written an ItemAdded event recevier on the Document Library where the PDF document is created by Word automation services. It is not firing when the Word Automation Services adds a file to a Sharepoint document library.

If I manually add a file to debug the ItemAdded event receiver, it is getting triggered. I don't know why it is not getting triggered when the file is added from Word Automation Services.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a SharePoint designer workflow with an Email Activity. It gets triggered whenever word automation services adds the converted pdf file into the document library.